# Convergence of gamma distribution

Tags: self-study, convergence, gamma-distribution, iid

[image]

In this problem, X follows a gamma distribution with shape parameter 2 and scale parameter 1, the mean of such n independent and identical random variables should converge to 2. In my opinion, the answer should be 1 because the probability that mean will be equal to 2 will be sure. But the answer given in the book is 0. I am not able to understand why probability will be 0 for large n when mean of n iid gamma variates will be 2 surely using the WLLN. Please help me with the problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please add `[self-study]` tag and read its [wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).

Comment: Where is the missing link between the weak Law of Large Numbers and the result?

Comment: I cannot understand your point. Can you be more specific?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: what's $\mathbb{P}(X_i = 2)$ for any $i$? And what about a finite sum of $X_i$?

Comment: Are you saying that probability at a particular point of a continuous distribution is zero? Aren't you?

Comment: Yes, I am saying that.

Comment: Hence, the probability of sum being equal to a number will be zero. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, you are. If the sum is countable.

Comment: Ok, thank you. It was a trivial point but I could not thought of this point.

Comment: No prob. There is no such thing as a trivial question when one is learning. :)